# Replacing the last row value of a specific column value

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe `df` which looks something like this:

| key | id |
| --- | --- |
| x | 0.6 |
| x | 0.5 |
| x | 0.43 |
| x | 0.56 |
| y | 13 |
| y | 14 |
| y | 0.4 |
| y | 0.1 |

I'd like to replace the Last value for every `key` value with 0, so that the df looks like this:

| key | id |
| --- | --- |
| x | 0.6 |
| x | 0.5 |
| x | 0.43 |
| x | 0 |
| y | 13 |
| y | 14 |
| y | 0.4 |
| y | 0 |

I've tried the following:

```
for i in df['key'].unique():
   df.loc[df['key'] == i, 'id'].iat[-1] = 0
```

the problem is it does not replace the actual value in the df. What am I missing? and perhaps there's an even better (performing) way to tackle this problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`Series.duplicated`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.duplicated.html) for get last value per `key` and set `0` in [`DataFrame.loc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html):

```
df.loc[~df['key'].duplicated(keep='last'), 'id'] = 0

print (df)
  key     id
0   x   0.60
1   x   0.50
2   x   0.43
3   x   0.00
4   y  13.00
5   y  14.00
6   y   0.40
7   y   0.00
```

How it working:

```
print (df.assign(mask=df['key'].duplicated(keep='last'),
                 invert_mask=~df['key'].duplicated(keep='last')))
  key     id   mask  invert_mask
0   x   0.60   True        False
1   x   0.50   True        False
2   x   0.43   True        False
3   x   0.00  False         True
4   y  13.00   True        False
5   y  14.00   True        False
6   y   0.40   True        False
7   y   0.00  False         True
```

Another solution is simply multiple `id` column with boolean mask:

```
df['id'] = df['key'].duplicated(keep='last').mul(df['id'])
print (df)
  key     id
0   x   0.60
1   x   0.50
2   x   0.43
3   x   0.00
4   y  13.00
5   y  14.00
6   y   0.40
7   y   0.00
```

Comment: thanks for the explanation. comparing each method; 
`df.loc[~df['key'].duplicated(keep='last'), 'id'] = 0` seems to be the best performing.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`groupby.cumcount`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.cumcount.html) to access the nth row per group from the end (with `ascending=False`), and [boolean indexing](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing):

```
df.loc[df.groupby('key').cumcount(ascending=False).eq(0), 'id'] = 0
```

output:

```
  key     id
0   x   0.60
1   x   0.50
2   x   0.43
3   x   0.00
4   y  13.00
5   y  14.00
6   y   0.40
7   y   0.00
```

Intermediate:

```
  key     id  cumcount  eq(0)
0   x   0.60         3  False
1   x   0.50         2  False
2   x   0.43         1  False
3   x   0.56         0   True
4   y  13.00         3  False
5   y  14.00         2  False
6   y   0.40         1  False
7   y   0.10         0   True
```

You can easily adapt to any row, example for the second to last row per group:

```
df.loc[df.groupby('key').cumcount(ascending=False).eq(1), 'id'] = 0
```

For the third row per group:

```
df.loc[df.groupby('key').cumcount().eq(2), 'id'] = 0
```